# Create my own slideshow like views_slideshow and views_galleria?

Tags: javascript

I want to create my own slideshow module using view.
I want to use jquery/javascript provided by client and create slider using views.
In short i want to make my own module/slider like views nivo slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question lacks a lot of information about what you already have in place but I'll try my best to answer you. You have a couple of options here.

1. Clone the nivo_slider implementation an use your own javascript in place of nivo.
2. Add your JS to the page using [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) and call the necessary functions to init the js.